# How can i assert express `res.status(200).send({ hello: 'world' })` actually sent a 200 with the correct data?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express

I want to learn how to properly unit test an express endpoint, specifically just the handler code, and assert the correct status and data in the response.

I want to do this **WITHOUT** supertest as I have a helper lib with a bunch of middleware functions and I want to test those in isolation.

For a simple app like this

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const helloWorld = require('./helloWorld')

app.get('/', helloWorld)

app.listen(5000, () => console.log('we\'re up!'))
```

With a simple handler function like this

```
'use strict'

function helloWorld (req, res, next) {
  const data = {
    hello: 'world'
  }
  res.status(200).send(data)
}

module.exports = helloWorld
```

I have this test in the making

```
'use strict'
const helloWorld = require('./helloWorld')

describe('#helloWorld', () => {
  it('should return 200', () => {
    const req = {

    }

    const res = {
      status: function (code) {
        this.statusCode = code
        return this
      },
      send: function () {
        return this
      }
    }

    const next = () => {}

    helloWorld(req, res, next)
    // TODO: How to assert status was 200 and data sent was { hello: 'world' }?
  })
})
```

How can I assert the status of 200 and the data being `{ hello: 'world' }`?

**Update**
This works, but idk if it's a terrible idea to do things this way.

Updated test

```
'use strict'

const { expect } = require('chai')
const helloWorld = require('./helloWorld')

describe('#helloWorld', () => {
  it('should return 200', () => {
    const req = {

    }

    const res = {
      _status: null,
      _json: null,
      status: function (code) {
        this._status = code
        return this
      },
      send: function (json) {
        this._json = json
        return this
      }
    }

    const next = () => {}

    helloWorld(req, res, next)
    expect(res._status).to.equal(200)
    expect(res._json.hello).to.equal('world')
  })
})
```

Comment: It's not a terrible idea, it's just extra work that you'd get for free from a mocking library. If you don't want to use 3rd party code though then it's pretty much you're only option.

Comment: Only problem with my update is it doesn't work with handlers that make async calls.. Not sure how to handle that case.

Comment: Your updated question (solution) looks way better than any answers provided here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bring in a mocking / stubbing library (I personally tend to use [Sinon](https://sinonjs.org)) and mock the `res` object e.g.

```
// Setup stubs
const req = {};
const res = {
   status() {},
   send() {}
};
const next = () => {}
// Setup mock
const resMock = sinon.mock(res);
resMock.expects('status').once().withArgs(200);
resMock.expects('send').once().withArgs({ hello: 'world' });
// Invoke code with mock
helloWorld(req, resMock, next);
// Assert expectations
resMock.verify();
```

You can also use stubs or spies, for multiple function assertions though I find mocks nicer to setup.

Same example using spies instead of mocks

```
// Setup stubs
const req = {};
const res = {
  status() {},
  send() {}
};
const next = () => {};
// Setup spies
const statusSpy = sinon.spy(res, 'status');
const sendSpy = sinon.spy(res, 'send');
// Invoke code
helloWorld(req, res, next);
// Assert calls 
expect(statusSpy.calledOnceWith(200)).to.be.true;
expect(sendSpy.calledWithMatch({ hello: 'world' })).to.be.true;
```

If this was to be a common trend across many tests then you could setup like

```
const req = {};
const res = {
  status() {},
  send() {}
};
const next = () => {};
...
before(() => {
  // Setup spies once for test suite
  sinon.spy(res, 'status');
  sinon.spy(res, 'send');
})

it('should return 200', () => {
  helloWorld(res, res, next);
  expect(res.status.calledOnceWith(200)).to.be.true;
  expect(res.send.calledWithMatch({ hello: 'world' })).to.be.true;
})

afterEach(() => {
  // reset spies after each test
  res.status.resetHistory();
  res.send.resetHistory();
})
```

Comment: I've used sinon many times and hate it so much. Always causes weird side effects or unexplainable behavior. B/c of this i'm trying not to use it and trying to do this in a more pure way.

Comment: @Catfish can't say I've experienced similar problems, I've used it extensively in large projects for many years just fine. If you want to go down the "pure" route then you effectively need to reinvent the wheel ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Your example doesn't actually work. I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`

Comment: @Catfish bug, supposed to pass the mock not the original `res`, fixed

Comment: Was looking into sinon a bit more last night. Is there a way that I can do my assertions at the end instead of defining them up front and then doing `resMock.verify()`?

Comment: @Catfish sure, you can use spies instead and asset those at the end instead. I can update with an example of it helps

Comment: that'd be much appreciated. I'd like to see both ways. The sinon docs are just so hard for me to translate on how to apply to my actual use cases.

Comment: @Catfish see example, code not tested and written on my mobile device so let me know if I've made a mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `res.status()` and `res.send()` are actually calling the lower level node.js `http` methods, there is really not much more inline testing that you can do here. These express methods have been battle tested in several large production environments over the years by companies large and small, so you can trust that they are going to do their job.

A more helpful test could be making sure that your server is responding with the right responses entirely. What you can do is create a separate `test-server.js` file and use the `request` library to hit your server with several tests through `localhost:port`. This would mimic a client's interaction with your server.

```
const request = require('request');
const assert = require('assert');

// Example test
request('http://localhost:8080', (err, res, body) => {

  // Run your tests here
  assert.strictEqual(body.hello, 'world');
  assert.strictEqual(res.statusCode, 200);
  // .. etc
});
```

You can then run your `test-server.js` file every time you make a change to your server to test it.

Comment: You're missing the point though. I have a helper repo full of middleware functions. No express server in that project (and i definitely don't want to add one just to test middleware handlers)

Comment: @Catfish Hmm, I see. Maybe this article would be helpful? It talks about testing middleware directly instead of using supertest. https://medium.com/@morrissinger/unit-testing-express-middleware-behavior-in-ecmascript-2015-f1641ebb8040